# Change DOM URL without updating in address bar

Tags: url, dom, url-rewriting

I am using third party analytics script in my ASP.Net MVC site. The script logs the current URL from the "document.location.href". I want add some additional encrypted data  in the URL that is passed to the third party site. But i don't want to change the URL in the address bar has the user will also see the updated URL.

Eg:

**Url in Address bar** = "example.com/page1"

**URl in document.location should be** = "example.com/page1/{encryptedstring}"

So, when the third party script get the current URL the updated URL will be logged.

**Note**: I can edit the third party script to update the URL based on my needs. But i don't want to update it since it may cause some licensing problem .

Comment: This approach is a little bit strange. Wouldn’t it make more sense to trigger your third party analytics api with a custom url instead of altering the page url (without changing in address bar)?

Comment: @Matthi If we change the address bar it will be seen by the users too. The used is used for internal purpose only so i don't want the user to see it

Comment: Sure. This is why I suggested to trigger your analytics api manually with a url of your needs.

Comment: There are getting the URL from "document.location" in their script which is read only. I can download and modify the script to pass the URL of my needs. But i am afraid that it may cause some licensing problem. Is there a way to change the document.location URL without changing the address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.location` is read-only. So unfortunately you cannot set it directly or expect it to differ from the address bar url.